# List of defined constants associated with SQL data types?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Reference [this list](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.esqlc.doc/ids_esqlc_0123.htm) of defined constants and their integer values associated with SQL data types for IBM Informix.

My question is, is there such a list of constants for Microsoft SQL Server? Specifically, T-SQL in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure SQL Database previous versions, there has a  list [SQL Server Data Type Constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms136906(v=sql.105)).

[image]

But this content has been retired and may not be updated in the future. The product, service, or technology mentioned in this content is no longer supported.

In the latest Azure SQL Server or Azure SQL DB version, Microsoft does't provide the list for us. I don't if it has updated.

For now we can reference this document: [Constants (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#integer-constants), supports SQL Server and Azure SQL Database.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I wonder why they no longer support it? At any rate, you've answered my question: "There used to be, but no more."